# Why won't my JSP page load when I call it via a method in my Controller class?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to pass two values from a method in my controller class to a JSP page, the functionality in the controller seems to work but the JSP page won't load. The two values are an `average house price` and an integer value representing the `number of houses` returned from a database query. I take in a latitude and longitude value from a **different JSP page** and they determine the values returned from the database. (I don't want to pass the `average house price` and `number of houses` values back to that same JSP page where the latitude and longitude originally came from, but a new page).

In my controller class, I have a debug that prints the results from the database query successfully in my Eclipse console so I know the query works, I've also included a print statement to see if the `session` contains a value and it prints successfully. So it seems that the values are correct and ready to be sent to the **new JSP page** however the page I'm trying to load simply won't load and I've tried several different ways to fix this but none work (I'll go into these ways below).

At the moment I'm trying to use `HttpSession` to pass the values from the controller to the **new JSP page** like so:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String parseHousePrice(@RequestParam("latitude") double latitude, 
                                  @RequestParam("longitude") double longitude,                                                            
                                  HttpSession session) {

    // This passes the lat & long into a method that will query the database 
    // and store the result into the housePrice double varaible
    double housePrice = parseHousePrice.ParseHousePrice(latitude, longitude);

    // This gets the number of houses returned from the query
    // and stores it into the number_of_houses integer value 
    List<Double> housePriceList = parseHousePrice.getList();
    int number_of_houses = housePriceList.size();

    // Debug to show the query works successfullt
    System.out.println("The average house price for this area is: " + housePrice + " based on " + number_of_houses + " property prices in this area");

    // Assigning the values to session attributes 
    session.setAttribute("houseprice", housePrice );
    session.setAttribute("housepricelistsize", number_of_houses);

    // Debug that shows the session currently holds a value
    System.out.println(session.getServletContext());

    // New JSP page I want to pass the values to
    return "houseprice";
}
```

In my **new JSP page** I try to pass the values from above into the following `<p>` tags:

```
 <p th:text="${session.houseprice}" th:unless="${session == null}">[...]</p>
 <p th:text="${session.housepricelistsize}" th:unless="${session == null}">[...]</p>
```

Like I said above I've tried various methods of passing the values to the JSP page but none work and the page won't load.

I've attempted to use a `model` to pass the values through like so:

```
    model.addAttribute("houseprice", housePrice);
    model.addAttribute("housepricelistsize", number_of_houses);
```

I printed the model as a debug using a simple `System.out.println(model);` and this printed the correct values and names of values.

And I've attempted to create a `HousePriceObject` entity and create a list of these objects in the controller. I would then use a `ModelAndView` and return the name of the `ModelAndView` instead of the JSP page name (`houseprice`) at the end of the method in the controller class like so:

```
        ModelAndView map = new ModelAndView("houseprice");
        map.addObject("housepricesList", housepricesList);

        // Return the ModelAndView instead of "houseprice" JSP page
        return map;
```

And use a `<c:forEach>` loop to iterate through the list and print it on the JSP page but it still won't work.

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${housepricesList}" var="HousePrice"> 
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${HousePrice.housePrice}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${HousePrice.number_of_houses}"/></td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Am I missing something small here or am I going about this the completely wrong way. As I said the values seem to ready to be sent and I think they will print as soon as the page loads, but the page simply will not load. An advice would be appreciated!

**Edit** I have other JSP pages loading from the controller when the methods are called, however it seems the fact the particular method highlighted above has a lot more functionality (i.e. taking in data from one JSP page, querying the database, and printing the data to a new JSP page, etc) something stops the `houseprice` JSP page from opening.

For example, the JSP page will open when I run the method above without all the extra code.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String parseHousePrice(@Valid HousePrice housePriceObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    // houseprice.jsp will open but obviously has none of the data 
    return "houseprice";
}
```

Comment: What does _won't load_ mean?  Check the log - any error?  So there is a `houseprice.jsp` - where is it located within the project directory/folder structure?

Comment: By not loading I mean the `houseprice.jsp` page fails to open but there are no errors. The JSP page is located in  `src->webapp` folder with the rest of the JSP pages.

Comment: Are other JSPs invoked by a Controller?  Try changing the JSP to just static text, with no dynamic elements.  And enable debug logging level.

Comment: Hey Andrew, I just updated the question as opposed to answering in the comments as I included some code. As for changing the JSP to static text do you mean dropping the quotation marks for the return?

Comment: I meant in the jsp, change it to `hello world`, so it only contains static text, with no imports, tags, etc. to see if a simple jsp will render.

Comment: Apologies Andrew, I didn't get what you meant. I made a new basic JSP page and I enabled the debugger but the page still won't open. I tried with a simple HTML page too and that didn't open either. I appreciate your help!